# TikZ: compiler error for coordinate calculating, calc library

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,%
    snakes,fit,scopes,arrows,calc,shapes.misc,positioning,%
    shapes.arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,backgrounds,decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    fuzzy/.style = {decorate, decoration = {random steps, segment length = 0.5mm, amplitude = 0.15pt}},
    ns/.style = {rectangle,minimum size = 6mm,rounded corners = 3mm,very thick,draw,font = \ttfamily,fuzzy}
}

\newcommand{\OL}[1]{{$\overline{x}_{#1}$}}
\newcommand{\NL}[1]{{${x}_{#1}$}}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
        >=latex, thick, 
        ns/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill = white, fuzzy, rounded corners = 3mm},
        decision/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill = gray, fuzzy, rounded corners = 3mm},
    ]
    \ttfamily
    \begin{scope}
        \coordinate node[decision] (nx12) at (0,0) {\OL{12}};
        \coordinate node[decision] (x5) at ($(nx12)+(1,1)$) {\NL{5}};
        \coordinate node[decision] (nx8) at ($(nx12)+(1,-1)$) {\OL{8}};

        \coordinate node[ns] (x2) at ($(x5)+(2,1)$) {\NL{2}};
        \coordinate node[ns] (nx7) at ($(nx12)+(2,-.5)$) {\OL{7}};
        \coordinate node[ns] (x4) at ($(x5)+(4,1)$) {\NL{4}};
        %\coordinate node[ns] (nx13) at ($(x4)+(1,1)$) {\OL{13}};
        %\coordinate node[ns] (x13) at ($(x4)+(1,-1)$) {\NL{13}};
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If one comments the `x4` everything goes smoothly, but now it is "<...>must have a (possibly empty) label<...>"

Comment: Your code compiles just fine for me.  What version of PGF are you using (I'm using PGF2.10)?

Comment: judging from the usage of the `snakes` library he is using an older version. Compiles fine here as well by the way.

Comment: @wh1t3: I do remember your saying about the "deprecated" snakes, thanks... \pgfversion gives 2.00... Thanks guys, have to update my pgf.

Comment: Hm, funny thing is that now I've updated to pgf 2.10: went to sourceforge and unpacked the entire thing into ~/texmf. But running pdflatex again gives the same error, although \pgfversion says 2.10

Comment: SOLVED: updating the pgf installation (as above) plus removing the space between \coordinate[ns]_(x4) did the trick. Now (I know there is no topic discussion in comments) what's wrong with the space? I have a Finnish keyboard, and sometimes when compiling C-programs gcc also complains about "stray \302 in line x", so these two issues can be connected...

Comment: Given that this was solved by updating PGF, we'll probably close this as "Too Localised" to remove it from the unanswered queue and because it's unlikely that the same problem will occur to someone else.  As for the space .. no idea!  Maybe your keyboard or editor inserts strange versions of space, I'd run the file through a Perl script (or other) that checks the unicode position of each character and look for oddities.